# Likelihood function as number of observations increases

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, asymptotics, exponential-family

If we have $n$ iid observations from some $X \sim p(\cdot|\theta)$, what happens to the likelihood function $p(x_1,\dots,x_n|\theta)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

I plotted the product of several $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and it got flatter and more spread out as I took more products. Is it generally true that the likelihood of $n$ observations gets more and more disperse as $n$ increases?

E.g. suppose the likelihood is in the exponential family, which has the form
$$p(x_1, \dots, x_n|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n h(x_i) \exp \bigg\{ \theta^\top \big(\sum_{i=1}^n T(x_i)\big) - n A(\theta)\bigg\}$$

I'm having trouble visualizing what happens as $n$ increases in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three slides from my [statistical modelling course](https://sites.google.com/view/statistical-modelling/home) illustrating why the average log-likelihood function concentrates with the number $n$ of iid observations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This second picture represents $L_n(\theta;\mathbf x)^{1/n}$ as $n$ increases. This function stabilises around its (entropy) limiting function
$$\exp\int\log p(x|\theta) \text dF(x)$$

Comment: I can't access the course without login, but this is great, thank you!

Comment: the second picture doesn't seem to converge to a delta function, why is that? What is $\mathcal{P}(3)$?

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused. If we're summing log likelihoods then it seems like the overall log likelihood will become more diffuse. And even though the average of the log likelihoods approaches its expectation, I don't understand why that relates to concentration

Comment: I also don't think I understand the first image. Does the sequence of likelihoods correspond to increasing $n$? Why does the peak height decrease? (Seems like the spike gets both narrower and shorter, which doesn't make sense)

Comment: In the sequence of Poisson likelihoods (Fig. 1), the scale decreases with $n$. Rescaling with a power $1/n$, the rescaled likelihood, function of $\theta$, converges to the function of $\theta$ in slide #2, not to a Dirac mass function. Since$$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_i \log f(x_i|\theta)$$converges to a negative quantity, obviously$$\sum_i \log f(x_i|\theta)$$diverges to $-\infty$...

Comment: I see, just to make sure I get it - so the scaled-down log likelihood converges to the model $ \log p(x|\theta)$ as $n$ increases, by LLN. (You've plotted likelihood, not log likelihood, right?) And the unscaled log likelihood goes to $-\infty$ while the likelihood turns into something very spread out and near 0. @Xi'an

Comment: Answer to the first question: no. $L_n(\theta;x_1,\ldots,x_n)^{1/n}$ converges almost surely (the $\mathcal L$ is not needed here) to$$\exp\int\log p(x|\theta) \text dF(x)$$not to $p(x|\theta)$ (for one thing there is no $x$ in the limit).

Comment: What is the difference between $L$ and $\mathcal{L}$? (Sorry, I am pretty new to statistics) Is $L_n$ the empirical log likelihood while $\mathcal{L}$ is the 'true'/model log likelihood?

Comment: I think I get it, thanks a lot for your help. Would you have any suggested references on asymptotics of the likelihood function?

Comment: Not an introductory reference.